# Which java http client supports status code 102 Processing?

Tags: java, http, webdav

Our company should invoke a REST-like service over HTTP that responds status code `102 Processing` for lengthy (time-consuming) operations. As I have understood, 102 Processing is not really a part of the official HTTP standard, but [an extension for the WebDAV protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2518#section-10.1). Said that, it is not a WebDAV we try to access but a HTTP service that "borrows" this status code.

Which java library supports this?

Comment: What do you mean by "supports"? On the server-side you can write any kind of REST service that can set (almost) any value as the response status code. On the client-side (almost) any http library will read the response and return a status code and response body, whatever they are. There is nothing special in the `102 Processing` value itself.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin It is client-side I am looking for. 102 is an interim response, meaning like "wait, more is coming but I need some time" and I think this needs some special treatment of the client.

Comment: You will have to code that special treatment yourself, like when you perform the request and get 102 you should re-schedule the (same) request again or display some message asking the user to wait and click some button again. The http library knows how to handle 102 "technically" - pass the status code to you, but it does not know how to handle it "semantically" - reschedule/ask user/..., so you will have to do that.

Comment: Oleg, you are totally incorrect! That's not simple response. Server sends 102, and don't close connection. Then can send 102 again, several times, and finally 200ok with data. In same connection. So no scheduling same request, that would cause server to recalculate anew. That would be hard without library support.

Answer (score 4):

1) The HTTP specification defines a status code registry (http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes); it really doesn't matter in which specification a status code is described.

2) That being said, RFC 4918 (which obsoletes RFC 2518) does not define code 102 anymore (for lack of any implementations).

Comment: Interesting. However, I seem to have stumbled upon a (server-side) implementation, although not in a WebDAV context.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the 102 PROCESSING status seems useful in the following case:

The action is very long running, e.g., some complex database delete operation with cascades, or, on WebDAV, a big directory deep copy, etc.

I need this because in some environments the access is through a firewall and that has a 5 min timeout. If nothing comes across the TCP connection for more than 5 min, the connection is closed. On the server side this shows as an IOError connection closed, on the client side this also shows like a connection closed or timeout error message.

We use 102 PROCESSING because we need to keep our options open to still reply with a finall 200, 300 (redirect), or 400 (error), before we can write to the servlet output stream.

It is true that 102 PROCESSING isn't supported well. JETTY (server) has some rudimentary implementation and I have crafted something over it with a separate Thread that sleeps for 5 min, checks whether the servlet output stream is still not committed, then issues a response.sendProcessing() and goes to sleep again. Thread is killed as soon as actual output is written.

Apache HTTPD if used as a reverse proxy to this JETTY implementation passes these 102 PROCESSING responses through fine. But after 10 of them it throws an error.

The sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection isn't working well with this. I have a little test program:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.io.*;

public class urlcontest {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        URLConnection conn = new URL(args[0]).openConnection();
        System.err.println("URLConnection class: " + conn.getClass());
        if(args.length > 1)
            conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie",args[1]);
        conn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        conn.setDoOutput(false);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        InputStream in = null;
        if(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection) {
            HttpURLConnection hconn = (HttpURLConnection)conn;
            int responseStatus = hconn.getResponseCode();
            try {
                in = hconn.getInputStream();
                System.err.println("HTTP input: " + responseStatus);
            } catch(IOException e) {
                System.err.println("HTTP error: " + responseStatus);
                in = ((HttpURLConnection)conn).getErrorStream();
            }
        } else
            in = conn.getInputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
        int nread = 0;
        while((nread = in.read(buf)) > 0)
            System.out.write(buf, 0, nread);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

And with this I get the following behavior:

```
URLConnection class: class sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection
HTTP input: 102
HTTP/1.1 102 Processing

HTTP/1.1 102 Processing

HTTP/1.1 102 Processing

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: ...
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: ...
Server: Jetty(6.0.1)

<html>...</html>
```

So, clearly, it takes the first 102 PROCESSING as the final response, and then everything else is read from the input stream, blocking during the pauses.

If I could find the source code of this or another HttpURLConnection implementation I would do something to make it work.

Somehow it should already handle the 100 CONTINUE response also. It shouldn't be too hard to do.

Comment: FWIW, this is a documented bug: <https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8170305>